# keep firebase function running

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have created a firebase function that fetched data from two websites via their API.

I want that function/script to be triggered once then keep requesting those two websites with regular interval.

The code I wrote :

```
setInterval(() => {

    rootRef.on('value', (snap) => {
        airtableApiKey = snap.val().airtable_key;
        airtableBase = snap.val().airtable_base;
        orionxApiKey = snap.val().orionx_key;
        orionxApiSecret = snap.val().orionx_secret;
        functionTimer = snap.val().function_timer;
        functionStatus = snap.val().function_status;
        geminiCoin = snap.val().gemini_coin;
        orionxCoin = snap.val().orionx_coin;


        if (!isNaN(Number(functionTimer)) && Number(functionTimer) !== 0 && functionStatus.toString().toLowerCase() === 'on') {
            trigger(airtableApiKey, airtableBase, orionxApiKey, orionxApiSecret, functionTimer, functionStatus, geminiCoin, orionxCoin).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    });
}, Number(functionTimer) * 1000);

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
});
```

In this case code inside setInterval executes for about a minute then stops automatically.

I have tried moving the setInterval code inside the express route, gives the same result.

Like this :

```
   exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 setInterval(() => {

        rootRef.on('value', (snap) => {
            airtableApiKey = snap.val().airtable_key;
            airtableBase = snap.val().airtable_base;
            orionxApiKey = snap.val().orionx_key;
            orionxApiSecret = snap.val().orionx_secret;
            functionTimer = snap.val().function_timer;
            functionStatus = snap.val().function_status;
            geminiCoin = snap.val().gemini_coin;
            orionxCoin = snap.val().orionx_coin;


            if (!isNaN(Number(functionTimer)) && Number(functionTimer) !== 0 && functionStatus.toString().toLowerCase() === 'on') {
                trigger(airtableApiKey, airtableBase, orionxApiKey, orionxApiSecret, functionTimer, functionStatus, geminiCoin, orionxCoin).catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        });
    }, Number(functionTimer) * 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't keep a function running indefinitely in Cloud Functions.  It's not supported.  All functions will time out eventually.  The default is 60s and the max is 9m by configuration in the Cloud console.

If you want to schedule some work to be done in Cloud Functions, you need to provide your own scheduler.  The team is looking into ways to schedule events, but there are no timelines for that solution.

Cloud Functions are meant to do their work as quickly as possible.  They are not meant for tasks of indefinite length.  If you need to keep some code running indefinitely, use App Engine or some other container that you control.